# "Have your friends had..." VS "Did your friends have..."

Tags: present-perfect, past-simple

I'm translating this sentence from Russian into English.

> Have your friends had/did you friends have a vacation in Spain? - No, they were going to, but changed their mind.

I'm wondering about the following: we are asking about the news, we don't know about that fact in the moment, but at the same time it can be a past event having nothing to do with the present situation (may be we know the exact past time).

So, which one is more preferable having no definite context?

Comment: We generally "take" vacations rather than "having" them.

Comment: @StoneyB, ok, this typo is the result of my not-native origin. I'll remember it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to phrase it:

> Did your friends go on that vacation to Spain? No. They were going to,
>   but changed their mind.

By using the word "that" it signals a specific vacation that they had in mind.

In American, we do not "have" vacations. We go on vacation, or take a vacation.